# app not launch from recent apps after changing launcher icon via activity-alias in 5.0+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-activity-alias

After changing app launcher icon to a new one with `activity-alias` method, I exit from app via back button, and when I try to start app from recent apps (Recent Tasks) in android 5.0+, app won't launch. and in some source codes it toasts: "Could not start " and to my case even not toast anything.

but there is an app [Textra SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=en), which can change launcher icon and after changing Icon, app starts normally even from recent apps.

how can solve this issue?

here is `AndroidManifest.xml` code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.sid.appiconlauncher.MainActivity-Red"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_red"
        android:label="@string/app_red"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.sid.appiconlauncher.MainActivity-Green"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_green"
        android:label="@string/app_green"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.sid.appiconlauncher.MainActivity-Blue"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_blue"
        android:label="@string/app_blue"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by preventing app from close by adding `moveTastToBack()` method in `onBackPressed()` without calling `super` method in root activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

with this, app not close, but move to back, like when you click on home button and never this issue happened.